# Cypress Package.json for multiple browsers, environment, testsuites

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, package.json

My package.json of cypress project looks something like this:

```
    "scripts": {
        "clean:allure": "rm -R -f cypress/reports && rm -R -f cypress/screenshots && rm -R -f  cypress/videos",
        "pretest_Stage": "npm run clean:allure",
        "scripts_Stage": "cypress run --env configFile=stage --browser chrome --spec cypress/integration/UI/test/test1.feature",
        "scripts_Stage:reg": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@reg' --browser chrome --env configFile=stage",
        "scripts_Stage:smoke": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@smoke' --browser chrome --env configFile=stage",
        "scripts_Stage:all": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@reg or @smoke' --browser chrome --env configFile=stage",
        "generate-allure-report": "allure generate cypress/reports/allure-results --clean -o cypress/reports/allure-report",
        "posttest_Stage": "npm run generate-allure-report",
        "test_Stage": "npm run scripts_Stage || npm run posttest_Stage",
        "test_Stage:reg": "npm run pretest_Stage && (npm run scripts_Stage:reg || true) && npm run posttest_Stage",
        "test_Stage:smoke": "npm run pretest_Stage && (npm run scripts_Stage:smoke || true) && npm run posttest_Stage",
        "test_Stage:all": "npm run pretest_Stage && (npm run scripts_Stage:all || true) && npm run posttest_Stage"
      },

I basically have different commands for tetSuite type.
```

Now I need to further add commands depending on browser and environment config file.
I created a sample for multiple environemnts, Now do I need to repeat all commands for n number of browsers ?

```
    "scripts": {
        "clean:allure": "rm -R -f cypress/reports && rm -R -f cypress/screenshots && rm -R -f  cypress/videos",
        "pretest_Stage": "npm run clean:allure",
        "scripts_Stage": "cypress run --env configFile=stage --browser chrome --spec cypress/integration/UI/test/test1.feature",
        "scripts_Stage:reg": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@reg' --browser chrome --env configFile=stage",
        "scripts_Stage:smoke": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@smoke' --browser chrome --env configFile=stage",
        "scripts_Stage:all": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@reg or @smoke' --browser chrome --env configFile=stage",
        "generate-allure-report": "allure generate cypress/reports/allure-results --clean -o cypress/reports/allure-report",
        "posttest_Stage": "npm run generate-allure-report",
        "test_Stage": "npm run scripts_Stage || npm run posttest_Stage",
        "test_Stage:reg": "npm run pretest_Stage && (npm run scripts_Stage:reg || true) && npm run posttest_Stage",
        "test_Stage:smoke": "npm run pretest_Stage && (npm run scripts_Stage:smoke || true) && npm run posttest_Stage",
        "test_Stage:all": "npm run pretest_Stage && (npm run scripts_Stage:all || true) && npm run posttest_Stage",


        "pretest_Prod": "npm run clean:allure",
        "scripts_Prod": "cypress run --env configFile=stage --browser chrome --spec cypress/integration/UI/test/test1.feature",
        "scripts_Prod:reg": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@reg' --browser chrome --env configFile=Prod",
        "scripts_Prod:smoke": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@smoke' --browser chrome --env configFile=Prod",
        "scripts_Prod:all": "npx cypress-tags run -e TAGS='@reg or @smoke' --browser chrome --env configFile=Prod",
        "posttest_Prod": "npm run generate-allure-report",
        "test_Prod": "npm run scripts_Prod || npm run posttest_Prod",
        "test_Prod:reg": "npm run pretest_Prod && (npm run scripts_Prod:reg || true) && npm run posttest_Prod",
        "test_Prod:smoke": "npm run pretest_Prod && (npm run scripts_Prod:smoke || true) && npm run posttest_Prod",
        "test_Prod:all": "npm run pretest_Prod && (npm run scripts_Prod:all || true) && npm run posttest_Prod"
      },
```

Is there a smarter way to add command's in package.json ??? The way I see it I need to repeat each command with following variables:

"scripts_" i.e. "scripts_Stage_Chrome_Smoke"

Comment: I cannot provide the code since it is for work, but we created a CLI with InquirerJS https://www.npmjs.com/package/inquirer and basically built all those options like you have and have dropdowns to select the options. Would recommend because we had tons of commands like you.

Comment: @cdcastillo but if i want to run my project through pipeline then seeking options from user at run time would not be possible. OR is there a way to do that as well with inquirer ?

Comment: Unsure. We use it for local machines, and have a few defined, but useful pipelines to test those scenarios. Sorry I am unable to help further.